# Script que dê a quantidade de um determinado termo de uma página (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, gostaria de saber quantas vezes o termo "**]   =   new entry (**" aparece na página.

```
the_entries[228]    =   new entry ( "http://www.respondi.com.br/2017/03/como-o-cristao-deve-se-posicionar.html","Como o cristão deve se posicionar politicamente?","tags","</br> <a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/F-rdTFbX-yk?autoplay=1%20' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer;width:50px;height:40px;'  src='logos/youtube-2-1.svg'/></a>");


the_entries[229]    =   new entry ( "http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-01/#como-os-dons-se-manifestam-na-igreja","Como os dons se manifestam na igreja?","tags","</br> <a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/GNfiv2RrqTI?autoplay=1%20' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer;width:50px;height:40px;'  src='logos/youtube-2-1.svg'/></a>");
```

Comment: Que página? De onde vem esse conteúdo? O que é `the_entries` e `entry`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, é uma página de busca, em javascript, mas sempre que gero uma nova linha, como a que coloquei acima, tenho que mudar a quantidade de linhas no script, então gostaria que isso fose feito dinamicamente, ou seja toda vez que eu adicionasse uma linha o quantitativo fosse atualizado automaticamente:
esta é a página, no final está a parte de quantidade:
http://leituracrista.com/indice 
Obrigado por perguntar!

Comment: Não basta pegar o número de elementos do *array* com `the_entries.length`?

Comment: Sim pode ser, como posso fazer isso? acho até que essa é a pergunta correta. rsrs

Comment: Resolvido @AndersonCarlosWoss, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicionando a seguinte linha para pegar o total de entradas:

```
entradas = the_entries.length
alert(entradas);
```